# Hand Gesture recognition on windows phone 8

Tags: android, opencv, windows-phone-8

I am trying to develop a windows phone 8 app to detect hand gestures. I am trying to use open cv for this, but saw that there are no supported versions for windows phone yet. After some searching on google for this, I found that it is possible to port native code from android to windows phone 8.

http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-usage-models.html

I want to know what I should keep in mind when trying to port such an application from android to windows phone 8.

Also, currently I am trying to use fastcv for this case, but there is a lack of documentation for windows phone . Can someone suggest a good tutorial to get started with fastcv on windows phone 8.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is much too broad for StackOverflow and seeks references to tutorials. Do you have a specific programming question related to the port of your application?

Comment: I sincerely apologise if I did something wrong by asking such questions, but as i mentioned, i am trying to use fast cv for windows phone, and yet don't know how to use it. So i wanted to get some tutorials in order to get started.

Comment: Questions that are a better fit would be something like, "I've got the source for FastCV, and when I compile it, X happens, and I can't figure it out."

Comment: Thanks. I will try to get in a bit more into this before I post any updates.